# shell touch command dose not work inside Makefile

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

Inside Makefile:

```
generate:
    touch file{1..10}
```

run it with `make`

and I get a single file name file{1..10} and not 10 different files.
The `touch` commands works properly on the shell.

Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make invokes shell as specified in the variable called `SHELL`. The default value for *nix systems is `SHELL=/bin/sh`.

Set `SHELL=/bin/bash` (or whatever) to make it working.

Note: unlike other make's variables, `SHELL`'s value is never imported from an environment (if running under POSIX OS; this is not true for native Windows builds).

Comment: Thanks now it works, I thought _make_ was watching environment variables that already was /bin/bash. I added the line you said in the makefile and now it works :)

Comment: @Miao Normally make imports its variables from the environment whenever possible. But `SHELL` is an exception -- it's never set from an environment.

Comment: I'm pretty sure there's *no* version of make that imports the user's SHELL value.  That would be a disaster: consider if someone using `csh` or `fish` or some other very different shell: the makefile would completely not work.  Maybe there are special rules for Windows, I forget.

Comment: @MadScientist `Maybe there are special rules for Windows` Yes, any "fish" is a lesser evil than "cmd", so under Windows gmake may search for shell "in unusual places" such as SHELL or PATH environment variables. It should be described [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Choosing-the-Shell.html), I believe. But neither Cygwin nor MSYS do that, only native Windows build.